# Does the Nikon Coolpix S7000 support an IR remote?

Tags: nikon, remote

On neocamera.com, it says that the Nikon Coolpix S7000 supports infrared remote control. Will this work with the official Nikon's IR remote control? Or, is it just a false information? I can't seem to find more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

**No. It doesn't support an IR remote**. Nikon's own website doesn't list an IR remote control among [the accessories for the S7000](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/compact-digital-cameras/coolpix-s7000.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-Accessories), and [the FAQ on their site for the S7000](http://answers.nikonusa.com/answers/7022/product/COOLPIX-S7000/nikon-inc-coolpix-s7000-questions-answers/questions.htm) has answers to this question that say No.

However, the S7000 *does* support Wi-Fi and NFC, and can be remote controlled from a smartphone app.

Comment: Then, is there any $100~200ish budget camera that supports IR?

Comment: @HizzGom, [we don't really do shopping questions here](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3957), because of the narrow focus and lifespan. But unless you're looking at _very_ old dSLRs, chances are good, you won't find one. It's a feature typically reserved for higher-end cameras. Why won't the NFC/Wi-Fi solution work for you? RF remotes are typically better on reliability and range than IR ones.

Comment: a kickstarter project (Foldio 360) seems to have this function where it sends out ir signals to take photos. That's why I'm specifically finding this typical function.

Comment: @HizzGom The only Foldio 360 I can find looks like it's for smartphone photography, no other cameras supported, and I don't see IR mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @inkista The Specifications of the Foldio 360's Kickstarter page lists "IR Sensor: Wireless communication with DSLR (Operated at 920nm & support Canon, Nikon, Pentax, SONY)"

Comment: Thanks, missed that. @HizzGom, instead of asking for a specific camera, you might want to edit this or the other question you asked to basically state your problem is finding a camera that's compatible with the Foldio 360.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @inkista I made an another thread already about that. Lack of information led me like this :)

Answer (score 0):

The Nikon Coolpix S7000 supports remote trigger via WiFi, not IR. You can see this in its [specification page](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/s7000) next to the label *Remote Trigger*.

*The camera search engine used to show all wireless and IR remote as one filter but it is fixed now.*

Answer (score 0):

Page 117 of the [Coolpix S7000 manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/F3GCi00WbjhG02lKB2h24itr7D32/S7000RM_(En)04.pdf) indicates that the camera shutter can be triggered using a 'smartdevice'.