# How can I find a cheap camera which has an IR remote?

Tags: remote, low-budget

I'm trying to find a camera that supports IR remote shots. My preferred budget is between $100 to $200. Can anybody help me find a camera that fits in my criteria?

Comment: I saw in [your other recent question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/75666/11924) that you are looking for IR compatibility for the Foldio 360 Kickstarter project. Is that what this question is about?

Comment: @scottbb Yes, I'm finding a camera that fits for foldio 360 right now. I do not mind which type, but I would prefer it would be 'new', but used is okay if budget is not allowed that much

Answer (score 1):

There are several sites which feature catalogs of cameras, searchable by feature. Unlike a Stack Exchange question with answers listing current possibilities, these databases are kept up to date by design. Unfortunately, the one at [Neocamera](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) doesn't appear to have "has remote" as a search option, but Digital Photography Review does — see [this search result list](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras?utm_campaign=internal-link&utm_source=mainmenu&utm_medium=text&ref=mainmenu#criterias=SpecsRemoteControl&paramSpecsRemoteControl=Yes). They don't have a way to narrow by price, but that's not too much of a hardship as they do list estimated current prices (they're owned by Amazon, so... that's easy) and you can just go through until you find a hit.

Perhaps more importantly for your case, though, they don't differentiate by IR vs. other technology — my new Fujifilm camera uses Wifi plus a smartphone app. For many people, the exact technology involved is not such a big deal, but from [this comment thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75666/does-the-nikon-coolpix-s7000-support-an-ir-remote#comment129255_75672) it looks like you're looking specifically for something to work with the [Foldio360](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/orangemonkie/foldio360-a-smart-turntable-to-create-stunning-360/description). In that case, as @scottbb notes, the Kickstarter says they support Canon, Nikon, Pentax, and Sony — I think *probably* they support anything that does IR triggering on a similar frequency, but... not necessarily. I'd check first. Or, narrow your search to just these brands, and rule out the ones that are "Yes (via smartphone)".

Your budget is quite low, so I think you might be best served starting with older cameras and then searching for them used.

Comment: TIL - dpreview is owned by Amazon.

Comment: @scottbb [Since 2007](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/1690663587/amazonacquiresdpreview)!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find a camera that supports IR remote shots. My preferred budget is between $100 to $200.

If you're willing to buy used, there are lots of options. For example, used Canon Rebel XT's are usually priced between $100 and $150, and that'd leave room in your budget to buy the Canon RC-6 infrared remote control, list price $30. The same control [works with practically any EOS camera](http://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/wireless-remote-controller-rc-6), and you may be able to find a newer used model that's still in your budget.

Comment: I'm trying to find it on mirrorless or on compact digital; cameras too